# how do i login to this site

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

noob here. Im trying to login to this site [odoo.com](https://odoo.com) with python but it isnt working. There is no evidence that im logged in (im getting 'none' from the print statement, this means the data im expecting if i were logged in isnt there) and i cant figure out why.

I think it has something to do with the 'onsubmit' in the form.

Here is my code

```
from cred import password, login
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Origin': 'https://www.odoo.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.odoo.com/web/login',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36',
}

def get_csrf():
    #get csrf_token
    r = s.get('https://www.odoo.com/web/login')
    soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
    g = soup.head.script.text
    g = g.split('\"')
    csrf_token = g[1]
    return csrf_token

with requests.Session() as s:
    csrf_token = get_csrf()
    data = {
        'csrf_token': csrf_token,
        'login': login,
        'password': password,
        'redirect': ''
    }
    r = s.post('https://www.odoo.com/web/login', headers=headers, data=data)
    re = s.get('https://www.odoo.com/my/databases')
    soup = bs(re.content,'html.parser')
    print(soup.find('div',{'class':'odoo-oe-databases'}))
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: "isnt working" doesn't mean anything. Please explain exactly what issue you are seeing.

Comment: I made an edit. Is that sufficient?

Comment: I suggest you dump the entire response page. There might be an error message that helps.

Comment: sorry im not sure what you mean

Comment: Add `print(re.content)` to see the entire page and actually see what you are getting back. It could be an error message.

Comment: no error message. Just html of https://www.odoo.com/my/databases

Comment: It sounds like you are logging in - no login error, able to see the first page after login. Is there any kind of "login badge" in the full page to indicate if you are logged in? and silly question: when you log in manually you can see these databases?

Comment: I might actually be logged in. The print statement was supposed to be my 'login badge' because i initially thought that tag and class only existed if i was logged in but on closer inspection, it is also there when im not logged in. But for some reason, soup.find cannot locate it either way. My new 'badge' is the 'logout button' (which i found) because there is no other evidence that im logged in. and yes i see the databases when i log in manually, but not in the dump. Any idea why?   Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: I can only suggest watch web traffic in f12 console when logging in manually and see if there is any difference v

Comment: You can do it easy with playwright, if you want i can post the answer which i just did and it works.

Comment: yes please. ill appreciate if you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easy with playwright. Put your login and password.
If you want to use it in headless mode put **headless=True**.
There you have playwright documentation: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=False)
    baseurl = "https://www.odoo.com/web/login"
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(baseurl)
    page.fill('#login', 'login email')
    page.fill('#password', 'your password')
    page.click("button[type='submit']")
    elementHandler = page.wait_for_selector(".oe_database_information")
    print("Database text: " + elementHandler.text_content())
    print("Database all html: " + elementHandler.inner_html())
  #  print(page.content())
    browser.close()
```

Be carefully, when i did a lot of request, they ban me for one minute.
I hope I have been able to help you.

Comment: got this error `Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop. Please use the Async API instead.` in spyder but it works fine in vscode. I guess i couldnt find what i was looking for initially because of the js. So playwright or selenium was the way to go. Thanks